# Change only the text font (and not the math font)

Tags: fonts

I would like to use one external font (GFS Artemisia) but I would like to preserve the main mathematical font. I did a search but I did not find something similar.

**Any ideas please?**

*My preable is the following:*

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}

\begin{document}  etc
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just do `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{artemisia}` instead of `\usepackage{gfsartemisia}`. But you may have problems with accents.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your comment. It works! But, why did we write "\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{artemisia}" instead of "\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{gfsartemisia}"? Is there a general way? What if we have other fonts?

Comment: That's the name of the font, as found in `gfsartemisia.sty`. There's no general rule.

Comment: Just a suggestion to give a minimal working example (generally from `\documentclass` till `\end{document}`) instead of just giving the preamble.

Comment: @pushpen.paul Thanks for your suggestion. I ll keep it in my mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL,DR

Use `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{artemisia}` instead of `\usepackage{gfsartemisia}` and hope for the best.

## Long answer

The `gfsartemisia` does several things other than changing the text font. In particular it does `\usepackage{txfonts}`, which changes the math fonts to a (bad) version of Times.

You might find difficulties with accents, because the font has them in nonstandard positions, but apparently this is fixed if you load the T1 font encoding.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{artemisia}

\begin{document}

'a \"a

\foreignlanguage{english}{\'a\`a\"a\~a}

$a+b=3$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different strategy could be using `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution`, to only change the Greek font to Artemisia.

Note: see edit history for a previous solution using the `substitutefont` package, now declared obsolete.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{\rmdefault}{artemisia}

\begin{document}

'a \"a abgde

\foreignlanguage{english}{\'a\`a\"a\~abcdef}

$a+b=3$

\end{document}
```

[image]